# Add up Time Used in Minutes for Spreadsheet or Doc Table

Tags: google-sheets

I have looked at adding or subtracting time for spreadsheet, but haven't found a way to easily do this yet:

Suppose I start the clock at 7am.
I would like to have a way to calculate the accumulated minutes for the tasks to be done and display what the current time should be after having completed the said task (input as minutes).

In the example below, A is the input in minutes, B is the calculated current time from the minutes from 7am. It goes on down the rows. I expect some formatting manipulations would be need as well for time.

```
A     |  B     | C
0min  | 7:00am | Start
10min | 7:10am | warmup
5min  | 7:15am | techniques
4min  | 7:19am | first drills
```

Hope this is something easy. I just can't quite figure where to start looking correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With A3:An formatted as number as shown and B2:Bn formatted as time as shown then in B3:

```
=B2+A3/1440
```

copied down to suit should serve.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @pnuts this is nice and and simple. I thought it might have had to be more complicated. Glad I asked. Thanks!